# gradle sync failed caused: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Today i stared my Android Studio and this error pop up, yesterday everything was fine...
really don't know what could go wrong, so i tried reinstall android studio, Android SDK build tools are installed, android SDK tools 25.2.2 also

help

from module app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "oo"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```

from project

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

EVENT LOG after starting android studio

```
> Error:Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException   at
> java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)    at
> java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:3813)   at
> java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:3800)     at
> com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.doCreateTempFile(FileUtilRt.java:399)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.createTempFile(FileUtilRt.java:361)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.createTempFile(FileUtilRt.java:341)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.createTempFile(FileUtilRt.java:334)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtil.createTempFile(FileUtil.java:1479)
>   at
> com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.GradleUtil.addInitScriptCommandLineOption(GradleUtil.java:1064)
>   at
> com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.GradleUtil.addLocalMavenRepoInitScriptCommandLineOption(GradleUtil.java:1057)
>   at
> com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.GradleUtil.addLocalMavenRepoInitScriptCommandLineOption(GradleUtil.java:1023)
>   at
> com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getExtraCommandLineArgs(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:345)
>   at
> org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:175)
>   at
> org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$300(GradleProjectResolver.java:73)
>   at
> org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:768)
>   at
> org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:752)
>   at
> org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:238)
>   at
> org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:112)
>   at
> org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:73)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:419)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:500)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:369)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after so many tries to actually make Android Studio 2.2.2 work, less painful and best solution is described down :), so for anyone who keep **having problem** with this new version of Android studio (**2.2.2**)... build won't work, even the bare installation won't complete successfully I recommend to **fresh install older version** - in my case **2.1.1**

**fresh installation:**

**1** open Control Panel --> Uninstall Android Studio --> select SDK and User Settings

**2** go: C:/Program Files/Android --> delete

**3** go: C:/Users/UserName/ and delete .android, .AndroidStudio2.2, .gradle and if any m2 folder

**4** download version 2.1.1, you can use this link: http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/2-1-1

**5** after downloading extract files go to folder android-studio/bin --> double click on studio.exe (32bit) or studio64.exe (64bit) which opens installer

**6** finally start writing some code ^^

Comment: After step 3 you can simply try **Build>Rebuild** Project. It will create all required files including **.gradle** folder again.Finally sync your project. **DONE**

Answer (score 22):

The steps below helped me get out of this situation:

- File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and Restart
- Build -> Clean Project

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue while editing the **project structure** of a **Flutter** project. My project was working fine before that.
So probably it was due to some misconfiguration.
I solved doing this:

- close AndroidStudio
- go to `your/project/path` and delete the `.idea` folder from your filesystem
- open again your project with android studio

I tried one `File > Invalidate Cache / Restart ..` before doing that, but it was probably useless.

Comment: Deleteing your/project/path/.idea folder helped me.

Comment: I deleted `your/project/path/.idea` and `your/project/path/.gradle` yolo (then reimporting - it worked)

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue when opening a React Native project incorrectly.

To fix this, I:

- File > Close Project
- Removed Project from the Welcome screen (cosmetic and not to get me into this mess again)
- Chose > Import project (Gradle, Eclipse, ADT, etc.)
- Chose my `react-native-app-folder/android`

After doing this, all errors were gone.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was resolved for me , after I made **a fresh installation of studio**.

For this

Step 1. **Uninstall Android Studio**. While uninstalling please make sure that you selected the additional option **Android User Settings** also.

Step 2. Goto **user's home** folder and **delete** folders **.gradle, .AndroidStudio**x.x(if it's still there). No need to delete or rename or relocate Workspace fodler.

Step 3. Now **install android studio again**.

Step 4. Let it download and build gradle.

Step 4. DONE.. :D

Comment: yes u tried that also, for me for some reason new version of android studio (2.2.2) won't work on my laptop, so i freshly installed older 2.1.1 version which work

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked was

1. Make sure source and assets are backed up.
2. Delete the project and recreate it.

I ran into this problem after adding the `Gdx-freetype` extension after the project was already created. When I recreated the project I made sure to check the box for it so it would be added when the project was created.

Answer (score 0):

Similar exception I got in the IntelliJ. Solved by using the proper version of JDK and Gradle that solved the issue

JDK Version : 11
Gradle Version : 5.2.1